# Reading xml-files on Google Drive using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, xml-parsing, urlfetch

I have some XML-files saved on Google Drive. I want to save their content into a spreadsheet.
Google Apps Script should be the tool:

- *DriveApp* locates files.
- *XmlService* reads XML-files.
- *SpreadsheetApp* stores the content.

I don't know how to read the content from a XML-file saved on Drive.

- DriveApp gives a downloadUrl but GAS doesn't allow downloading files.
- UrlFetchApp isn't authenticated.

It it impossible or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here a little code that may help you:

```
function xmlRead(){
  var id = "ID_OF_THE_FILE";
  var rawXml = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(rawXml).;
  // then it's your job to extract what you want from this XML

  var ssid = "ID_OF_THE_SPREADSHEET";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  ss.appendRow(["some stuff you extracted"]);
}
```