# Parse XML from Google Drive in Javascript (Google Scripts)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I would like to ask you, please, how to parse this XML file? I would like to work with a couple of child nodes.

```
<are:Ares_odpovedi xmlns:are="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_vreo/v_1.0.0" odpoved_datum_cas="2022-05-09T15:00:10" odpoved_pocet="1" odpoved_typ="Vypis_VREO" vystup_format="XML" xslt="klient" validation_XSLT="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_odpovedi.xsl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_vreo/v_1.0.0 http://wwwinfo.mfcr.cz/ares/xml_doc/schemas/ares/ares_answer_vreo/v_1.0.0/ares_answer_vreo.xsd" Id="ares">
<are:Odpoved>
 <are:Pomocne_ID>0</are:Pomocne_ID>
 <are:Vysledek_hledani>
  <are:Kod>1</are:Kod>
 </are:Vysledek_hledani>
 <are:Pocet_zaznamu>1</are:Pocet_zaznamu>
 <are:Vypis_VREO>
  <are:Uvod>
   <are:Nadpis>Výpis z veřejného rejstříku v ARES - elektronický opis</are:Nadpis>
   <are:Aktualizace_DB>2022-05-09</are:Aktualizace_DB>
   <are:Datum_vypisu>2022-05-09</are:Datum_vypisu>
   <are:Cas_vypisu>15:00:09</are:Cas_vypisu>
   <are:Typ_vypisu>aktualni</are:Typ_vypisu>
  </are:Uvod>
  ...
```

My code:

```
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/file/d/[fileID]").getContentText();
var data = XmlService.parse(xml);
Logger.log(data.type);
```

And I receive error:

```
Exception: Error on line 1257: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
```

Even though there are no tags "meta" and the last row in xml document is 1008.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/file/d/[fileID]").getContentText();
```

by

```
var xml = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();
```

---

As your script is using UrlFetchApp to retrieve a Google Drive file using a URL of the form `https://drive.google.com/file/d/[fileID]` your script is getting the HTML content of the file preview.

There are two possible paths, use a URL of the form `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=fileID` or use the Google Drive Service i.e. `DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob().getDataAsString()`.

If you will go for using the `UrlFetchApp` you should make the file public or to pass the appropriate credentials., considering this the most convenient solution is to use the Google Drive Service.

Resources

- [Reading xml-files on Google Drive using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38974802/1595451)